# How to solve Null check operator used on a null value. Rest API

Tags: flutter

My problem is that dataFromAPI is null, when it isn't supposed to be. I tried to check the variables and some more, and i can't see where is the null variable. I don't know if it's that or something else, because i've seen this error is more global than my last one.

Model

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final albaranesDeVentaDetalle = albaranesDeVentaDetalleFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle albaranesDeVentaDetalleFromJson(String str) =>
    AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String albaranesDeVentaDetalleToJson(AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle {
  VtaFacG vtaFacG;

  AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle({
    required this.vtaFacG,
  });

  factory AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle(
        vtaFacG: VtaFacG.fromJson(json["vta_fac_g"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "vta_fac_g": vtaFacG.toJson(),
      };
}

class VtaFacG {
  DateTime fch;
  String numFac;
  int clt;
  double totFac;

  VtaFacG({
    required this.fch,
    required this.numFac,
    required this.clt,
    required this.totFac,
  });

  factory VtaFacG.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VtaFacG(
        fch: DateTime.parse(json["fch"]),
        numFac: json["num_fac"],
        clt: json["clt"],
        totFac: json["tot_fac"]?.toDouble(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "fch": fch.toIso8601String(),
        "num_fac": numFac,
        "clt": clt,
        "tot_fac": totFac,
      };
}
```

The code that shows it

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:velneoapp/api/modelos/api_model_detalles_de_albaranes.dart';

class DetalleDeAlbaranView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DetalleDeAlbaranView({super.key, required this.index});
  final int index;
  @override
  State<DetalleDeAlbaranView> createState() => _DetalleDeAlbaranViewState();
}

//

class _DetalleDeAlbaranViewState extends State<DetalleDeAlbaranView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getData();
  }

  bool _isLoaded = true;

  AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle? dataFromAPI;
  _getData() async {
    try {
      String url =
          "https://demoapi.velneo.com/verp-api/vERP_2_dat_dat/v1/vta_fac_g/3?api_key=api123";
      http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      log("${res.body}");
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        log("hecho");
        dataFromAPI = AlbaranesDeVentaDetalle.fromJson(json.decode(res.body));
        _isLoaded = false;
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        throw ("Error during connection");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log("Error");
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Detalle de albaranes"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text("TOTFAC: "),
                Text(dataFromAPI!.vtaFacG.totFac as String),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text("FCH: "),
                Text("${dataFromAPI!.vtaFacG.fch}"),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text("NUM_FAC: "),
                Text(dataFromAPI!.vtaFacG.numFac),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error message is:

````
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building DetalleDeAlbaranView(dirty, state: _DetalleDeAlbaranViewState#d23f9):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
DetalleDeAlbaranView
main.dart:28
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _DetalleDeAlbaranViewState.build
detalle_de_albaran.dart:63
#1      StatefulElement.build
framework.dart:5198
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5086
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5251
#4      Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#5      ComponentElement._firstBuild
framework.dart:5068
#6      StatefulElement._firstBuild
framework.dart:5242
#7      ComponentElement.mount
framework.dart:5062
...     Normal element mounting (220 frames)
#227    Element.inflateWidget
framework.dart:3971
#228    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
framework.dart:6570
#229    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3708
#230    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
framework.dart:6153
#231    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
framework.dart:6595
#232    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#233    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#234    StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5251
#235    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#236    StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5274
#237    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#238    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#239    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#240    ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5417
#241    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#242    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#243    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#244    ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5417
#245    _InheritedNotifierElement.update
inherited_notifier.dart:107
#246    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#247    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#248    StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5251
#249    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#250    StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5274
#251    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#252    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#253    Element.rebuild
#254    ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5417
#255    _InheritedNotifierElement.update
inherited_notifier.dart:107
#256    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#257    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#258    StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5251
#259    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#260    StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5274
#261    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#262    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#263    StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5251
#264    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#265    StatefulElement.update
framework.dart:5274
#266    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#267    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
framework.dart:6442
#268    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#269    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
framework.dart:6442
#270    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#271    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#272    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#273    ProxyElement.update
framework.dart:5417
#274    Element.updateChild
framework.dart:3686
#275    ComponentElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5111
#276    StatefulElement.performRebuild
framework.dart:5251
#277    Element.rebuild
framework.dart:4805
#278    BuildOwner.buildScope
framework.dart:2780
#279    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
binding.dart:903
#280    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
binding.dart:358
#281    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
binding.dart:1284
#282    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
binding.dart:1214
#283    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
binding.dart:1072
#284    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#285    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#286    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════```

I don't exactly know where the null value is, because it says that the value I created IS null. This is the first REST API I do where it isn't a list, so idk if I messed up somewhere.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad practice:

```
 factory VtaFacG.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VtaFacG(
        fch: DateTime.parse(json["fch"]),
        numFac: json["num_fac"],
        clt: json["clt"],
        totFac: json["tot_fac"]?.toDouble(),
      );
```

Imagine your values inside your map don't exist. You will set a null value inside numFac which is of type String. You either make it of type String? or you just check if the value is null and set a default value in this case.

```
numFac: json["num_fac"] != null ?  json["num_fac"] : "",
```

or in shortform:

```
numFac: json["num_fac"] ?? "",
```

Check every variable which isn't nullable, not only numFac.

To your problem:

You make a call to an api. You send a request to the api, you wait for the response, parse the json, etc. This all takes time.

While you are making this call and waiting for the result, your build method is already being called. In your build method you are accessing the variable already, but it has not been set yet, because the whole thing runs asynchronously and takes time.

You have 2 options:

You use your flag which you already implemented. I don't know why your _isLoaded variable is default to true, you should set it to false and set it to true after the api call (Otherwise, this will confuse other developers.). Inside your build method you check if the data is already loaded and if not you show an empty Container or another widget like this:

```
return _isLoaded ? Scaffold(..) : Container();
```

Or option 2 is you use a FutureBuilder, which basically does the same but is an official Flutter widget. Here is an example from flutter:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to check it next time. But the error is still standing even tho I null checked every variable I found.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see the mistake, classic async error :P I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that was the cause. Thx a lot, I really didn't know how to solve it. Now I have another error, but I think I know how to solve it :D

Comment: If you get stuck, feel free to open a new question ^^